# How can I store the value of an entry to b used later

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, tkinter-entry, storing-data

I want to make a system to calculate the salaies of employee using OOP and tkiner
My problem is how to store the value of an entry to be used later

Comment: You can access whats currently in the entry widget with `entry.get()`, this returns a string.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The text typed in the entry widget can be accessed with `entry.get()` method.

---

### Example:

```py
entry = tkinter.Entry(root)
value = entry.get()
```

### Reference

- https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/entry.html

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the value of the Entry, you can use the `Entry().get()` function, or if you want the salaries in an integer, you can convert that to an integer `int(Entry().get())`. You can also use the text variable function. `e = Entry(root, textvariable=StringVar) e2 = e.get()`